# How to list all directory paths including a text?

Tags: directory, search, text

I need to list all directory paths including a text which is part of thier sub-directories. For example, the text is **"tpcc"**  and I have two paths including **tpcc** as following:

```
/home/arghy/sampledir1/**tpcc**-uva/subdir1/subdir2
/home/arghy/sampledir2/**tpcc**-postgre/subdir1/subdir2
```

I want to list these paths using a command and give "tpcc" as the aforementioned text. What is the command to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all directory pathnames from the current directory downwards that contain the particular string `tpcc`:

```
find . -type d -path '*tpcc*'
```

The `-path` predicate will match the pattern against the pathnames that `find` comes across, and if it matches the pattern, the current pathname will be printed.

If you *don't* want the pattern to be matched at the end of the current pathname, use `*tpcc*/*` as the pattern instead.  Matching a `/` somewhere after `tpcc` would cause `find` to find directories strictly *beneath* any directory whose name contains `tpcc`.

The `-type d` restricts the search to directories only.

Would you want to wrap this into a simple to use shell function:

```sh
pathfind () {
    case $# in
        1)  # only a string was given
            searchpath=.
            searchstring=$1
            ;;
        2)  # search path and string was given
            searchpath=$1
            searchstring=$2
            ;;
        *)  # anything else is an error
            echo 'Expected one or two arguments' >&2
            return 1
    esac

    find "$searchpath" -type d -path "*$searchstring*"
}
```

You could use this as either

```
pathfind tpcc
```

or as

```
pathfind /some/path tpcc
```

or

```
pathfind /some/path 'tpcc*/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The task you describe would be satisfied with

```
find . -type d | grep tpcc
```

but this will also list the "branch" directories, not just the "leaf" directories:

```
/home/arghy/sampledir1/tpcc-uva
/home/arghy/sampledir1/tpcc-uva/subdir1
/home/arghy/sampledir1/tpcc-uva/subdir1/subdir2
```

Is this okay or do you want to skip directories with more subdirs inside?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo find DIRECORY  -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -exec dirname {} \; | sort|uniq
```

check this Link: [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767396/linux-command-how-to-find-only-text-files)

فارسی:
با دستور بالا میتوانید پاسخ سوال خود را دریافت کنید. موفق و پیروز باشید

یاعلی ع

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to find pathnames containing a particular string.

Comment: now it is reformed.